# compare values in excel and highlight the leading number in B1

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, conditional-formatting, array

how do i compare column A which has repeats data against column B which has numbers and highlight the leading number. since the data has no patterns, not quiet getting it, Please help.
[image: attached screenshot]

Comment: What is the logic here? You get 5 from 6912, where does the 5 come from? You also state this is the "highest" but highest what?

Comment: the number 5 and the rest of the numbers are just there without any logic. highest from 6912s compared with the respective numbers

Comment: Are all the duplicated values in column A contiguous?  IOW, you have `6024` in the first two rows.   Can you have another `6024` in `A40:A42` and, if so, do you need the highest for each contiguous group, or do you consider all the `6024`s as a single group, looking for just a single highest?

Comment: all the 6024s as a single group,  and looking for just a single highest. these numbers in A are  kind of in order. so will not find 6024s in A40:A42

Comment: Select Column A and B, enter the formula to conditional formatting: *=($A1<>"")*($B1=MAX(($A$1:$A$100=$A1)*($B$1:$B$100)))*

Comment: Its working, but the group which has all 1 series of 8091 gets highlighted, thanks Lee

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an index column, so the conditional formula knows which to highlight in case of ties.

[image: Datasheet and formula]

For example I use the above data. The formula I use for the conditional formatting is:

`=INDEX($A$1:$A$8,MATCH(1, --(B1=$B$1:$B$8)*--(MAXIFS($C$1:$C$8,$B$1:$B$8,B1)=$C$1:$C$8),0))=A1`

The idea is

> to lookup the highest value in column C based on current group in column B, then return the unique index, which then will compared to current index. The returned boolean then can be used in conditional formatting.

**Note:** This works in conditional formatting custom formula, however I'm using Office 365 and it natively handle array formula. If this doesn't work for you, go ahead and make a helper column and conditional format based on that column. Remember that array formula must be entered using Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

---

`INDEX($A$1:$A$8`

This first part of the `INDEX` returns the unique index number in column A.

`MATCH(1`

This first part requires both conditions in the next argument to be `TRUE`.

`--(B1=$B$1:$B$8)`

This condition filters column B against current 'group' value.

> In row 1, the current group is 1234 so only data in row 1, 2, 3 will be checked (return `TRUE`).

`--(MAXIFS($C$1:$C$8,$B$1:$B$8,B1)`

This part finds the highest value in column C which is in current group,

`=$C$1:$C$8)`

then finds the appropriate row(s) that has that value (the highest in the group).

`,0`

the last argument of `MATCH` requires the result to return exactly `1` (as in the first argument)

`=A1`

compares the current index row with the returned index, converting it into TRUE-FALSE value that can be used by conditional formatting.